# Timer inside an object

Tags: c++, time

I want to have timer inside my object, that would count to eg. 10 seconds after that it would destroy itself.

I thought about something like this:

```
class A{
     int interval;
     void count(){
     /*clock starts putting value in interval*/
     if(interval < 10) delete this;
     };
};
```

Comment: If it's with a reference to PC clock or Wall clock, you may want to develop or use some sort of event system. Such as [`QTimer::singleshot`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) or [`boost::asio::deadline_timer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html#boost_asio.tutorial.tuttimer1)

Comment: How does the potential caller of A::count know, that the object expired? I would add a return value that indicates, that the object should be deleted now.

Comment: My bad, I want to delete it after a certain time. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should to checkDelete in main thread of the program.

   ```
   #include <time.h>

   class A{
       time_t m_tCreateTime;
       int m_iInterval;

       A():
          m_tCreateTime(time()), 
          m_iInterval(10) {
       }

       void checkDelete() {
           /*clock starts putting value in interval*/
           if( time() - m_tCreateTime > m_iInterval ) 
               delete this;
       }
   };
   ```
2. If you have multithreaded app and want to delete object independently from  in his own thread, you should to make sure, that you will not use this object from another threads.

Comment: Also your usecase is not clear for me. Maybe `boost::shared_ptr` will be more usefull?

Comment: I repeat - it's very bad usecase to delete object from inside by time. How another part of program to know about it? All links are stays in outside.